# recaptcha in odoo 14

Tags: odoo, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, odoo-14

I have tried to access **recaptcha feature** in **odoo 14** by configuring it using site key and secret key which i got from google recaptcha page but didn't get recaptcha image in my login page.

**Here are the steps that i followed:-**

- visited this url : https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create
- then added label
- selected recaptcha v3 as type
- added domain as localhost
- and accepted terms and conditions and clicked on submit button,
- got site key and secret from there and pasted in odoo.

But didn't get recaptcha on login or signup page.

Are my steps correct or anything i am missing?

Do anyone have any idea how to enable and use this feature?
Please guide me about this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add two keys in odoo settings
go to Admin > Settings > Integrations active reCAPTCHA and add your site key &  secret key